# How to label a cross tabulation table

Tags: r

I am conducting cross tabulation between two variables using the "prop.table()" function. How can I label the row, columns, and title to increase readability. code below.

`prop.table(table(hl$high, hl$midwest),1) * 100`

Comment: Hi Tyler, it would help to answer your question if you had reproducible example in it, have a look at some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It's a data.frame you can do whatever you like

```
  z <- prop.table(table(mtcars$cyl , mtcars$am),1) * 100
    rownames( z ) <- c( "Four","Six","Eight")
    colnames( z) <- c("Does Not Have","Does Have")
    print( z)
```

Comment: It's not a `data.frame`, it's a `table`, but `rownames()` and `colnames()` work for `table`s as well. By default, the rownames and colnames are filled in too. I think OP is asking about the labels overall, as you'd get with `table(mtcars[c("cyl","am")])`